# Sort date list in format DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sorting, date-and-time

I have a list of dates (ranging from 2007 to 2012) in the DD/MM/YYYY format and I need to sort this list.
My problem is, when I simply use `Sort[]` I get:

```
{"01/02/2007", "01/02/2008", "01/02/2009", "01/02/2010", "01/02/2011",...}
```

However, I need to sort this list to get something like:

```
{"02/01/2007", "03/01/2007", "06/01/2007", "08/01/2007", "10/01/2007",...}
```

After reading the StackExchange *Mathematica* forum I got the following code:

```
Flatten[SortBy[
  Partition[
   Table[DateString[
     datelist[[v]], {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}], {v, 1, 
     Dimensions[datelist][[1]]}], 1], 
  AbsoluteTime[{#[[1]], {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] &]]
```

It works... However, it takes almost 2 seconds to compute, and, worst, I get 4 error messages:

```
DateString::ambig: Warning: the interpretation of the string 02/01/2007 as a date is ambiguous. >>
DateString::ambig: Warning: the interpretation of the string 10/04/2012 as a date is ambiguous. >>
DateString::ambig: Warning: the interpretation of the string 09/04/2012 as a date is ambiguous. >>
General::stop: Further output of DateString::ambig will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

Is there any way to sort this list faster without getting error messages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Simon's data:

```
In[6]:= datelist = {"29/02/2008", "15/12/2007", "06/09/2007", 
   "06/10/2008", "05/03/2007", "24/01/2010", "19/06/2009", 
   "03/11/2009", "02/02/2010", "25/12/2009"};
```

We can just sort the data by the absolute time:

```
In[7]:= SortBy[datelist, AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] &]

Out[7]= {"05/03/2007", "06/09/2007", "15/12/2007", "29/02/2008", "06/10/2008",
         "19/06/2009", "03/11/2009", "25/12/2009", "24/01/2010", "02/02/2010"}
```

Comment: Simple and fast! Not the fastest code, but very simple to understand. It's the one I'm going to use! Thank you!

Comment: Date and time math still very slow in Mma. This is faster by converting the entire list to `AbsoluteTime`, sorting then mapping back to `DateString` ...like @VLC but without the intermediary step via `DateList`.

Answer (score 12):

A simple string-based approach is to swap the order of day/month/year, do the `Sort` and then swap back again:

```
(*  Example data  *)
datelist = DateString[# + AbsoluteTime[{2007, 01, 01}],
 {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}] & /@ RandomInteger[10^8, 10]
```

> {"29/02/2008", "15/12/2007", "06/09/2007", "06/10/2008", 
>   "05/03/2007", "24/01/2010", "19/06/2009", "03/11/2009", "02/02/2010",
>    "25/12/2009"}

```
With[{rule = a__ ~~ "/" ~~ b__ ~~ "/" ~~ c__ :> c <> "/" <> b <> "/" <> a},
 StringReplace[Sort@StringReplace[datelist, rule], rule]]
```

> {"05/03/2007", "06/09/2007", "15/12/2007", "29/02/2008", 
>   "06/10/2008", "19/06/2009", "03/11/2009", "25/12/2009", "24/01/2010", 
>   "02/02/2010"}

**Update**

A faster approach using the same string replacement and `Ordering`:

```
datelist[[Ordering@
   StringReplace[datelist, 
    a__ ~~ "/" ~~ b__ ~~ "/" ~~ c__ :> c <> "/" <> b <> "/" <> a]]]
```

Comment: Almost unreadable, but very fast. Well done!

Comment: @Simon Woods, I didn't try your code before... but now that I've tried it I'm impressed... 0.010001 seconds to sort my list... Fastest way for sure! TY

Comment: @Simon, it's faster! I though it couldn't be any faster than your previous code, but it is! It took only 0.006001 seconds to sort my list... Impressive! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can avoid the error messages by specifying how your dates are defined to correctly interpret ambiguous strings such as "01/02/2007":

```
Flatten[SortBy[
  Partition[
   Table[DateString[{datelist[[v]], {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}, {"Day",
       "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}], {v, 1, 
     Dimensions[datelist][[1]]}], 1], 
  AbsoluteTime[{#[[1]], {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] &]]
```

For the speed issue try this and let me know if it is actually faster:

```
DateString[#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}] & /@ (DateList /@ 
   Sort[AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] & /@ datelist])
```

As Mike suggested this piece of code can be actually reduced to:

```
DateString[#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}] & /@ 
   Sort[AbsoluteTime[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] & /@ datelist]
```

Comment: Simply perfect! Thank you!

Comment: The second option is even better! 
It took 0.904114 seconds to sort the list using the first code, and only 0.549069 seconds using the second option... Thank you!

Comment: You can map absolute times onto `DateStrings` so further speed improvements are available by skipping the intermediary `DateList` mapping step.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

And yet another way based on converting to integer lists and then finding their ordering:

```
sdl=datelist[[ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#, "/"][[{3, 2, 1}]] & /@ datelist// Ordering]];
```

Timing on 100,000 dates:

```
datelist = 
  DateString[# + AbsoluteTime[{2007, 01, 01}], {"Day", "/", "Month", 
      "/", "Year"}] & /@ RandomInteger[10^8, 10^5];

datelist[[ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#, "/"][[{3, 2, 1}]] & /@ datelist// Ordering]];   
// AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.658967, Null}

Comment: Hello image_doctor, I think there is a problem with your code... Although it was really fast (it took only 0.031004 seconds to sort my list), my final result was ordered in the MM/DD/YYY format...

Comment: @Rod Sorry I forgot you wanted reformatting as well .. hold on ....

Comment: @RodLm It's about twice as slow, but I hope that works for you.

Comment: It's a fast code! It took only 0.053006 seconds to sort my list. However, I would include Flatten[] in the code, because the sorted list was somehow partitioned... TY !

Comment: @RodLm Sorry the versions are changing a bit, I'm getting a flat result with the current version, do you get the same?

Comment: Thank you @image ! Now it takes 0.032004 seconds to sort my list and it's correctly formatted! TY!

Comment: @RodLm Glad you like it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's yet another way to sort and reformat your dates. It could be rewritten as a pure function, but some people find named parameters are easier to read.

```
f[dates_]:= DateString[#, {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year"}] & /@ 
    Sort[DateList[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] & /@ dates]
```

**Usage**

```
myDates = {"01/02/2007", "12/02/2007", "01/02/2008", "01/02/2009", "01/02/2010", 
  "06/01/2007", "01/02/2011"}

f[mydates]
```

> {"01/06/2007", "02/01/2007", "02/12/2007", "02/01/2008", \
>   "02/01/2009", "02/01/2010", "02/01/2011"}

**How it works**

First, Sort the list of dates, presently in {Day, Mon, Year} format , into a more convenient format (convenient for *Mathematica* to sort)

```
    Sort[DateList[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] & /@ myDates
```

> {{2007, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, {2007, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2007, 2, 12, 0, 0, 
>     0.}, {2008, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.},
>          {2009, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, {2010, 2, 1, 0,0, 0.}, {2011, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0.}}

Then, re-format the results to {Mon, Day, Year}.

```
DateString[%, {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year"}]
```